# RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (112) must match the size of tensor b (224) at non-singleton dimension 3 - Tucker Decomposition using tensorly lib

Tags: python, machine-learning, runtime-error, resnet, decomposition

Im facing a problem, that I'm not sure how to solve.
Im decomposing Resnet20, Resnet32 and Resnet56 using tucker decomposition with (partial tucker from tensorly).

For the rank estimation I'm using VBMF. The problem I'm facing is not with the decomposition (I think) but rather with the network architecture, as the Lambda layer is the problem
[Lambda Layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sThHp.png)
when I'm putting some input tensor to the layer to calculate the FLOPS and params etc. I get the error "RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (112) must match the size of tensor b (224) at non-singleton dimension 3".
I figured it's origin is in the lamda layer, but I don't want to play with the network architecture itself as I want to compare the original one with the decomposed.

Do you have any idea how I can solve the problem?
Maybe by manipulating the new layers, or the parameters.
[New Layers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxzjT.png)

I changed the architecture of  the lambda layer to, [new lambda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9y78D.png) and I know it works, because I tested it, but I think it's the wrong approach. I tried playing with the stride and padding in the new layers after decomposition but I always encountered the same error just with different values.

Thanks for help, the network architecture is from the reporitory - [ResNet Implementation](https://github.com/akamaster/pytorch_resnet_cifar10)

Comment: Can we get a text with paragraphs instead of just a wall of text, and the code as formatted text, not screenshots, as a [mcve] please? See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace the convolutional layers of your ResNet by factorized ones using a Tucker decomposition, you can directly use the layers provided in [TensorLy-Torch](https://tensorly.org/torch/dev/modules/generated/tltorch.factorized_layers.FactorizedConv.html#tltorch.factorized_layers.FactorizedConv). It also uses TensorLy under the hood just as you are to perform the decomposition but also returns an nn.Module that performs the factorized operation.